# SSIS - Parallel execution of same package

Tags: sql-server, ssis, parallel-processing

I'm trying to speed up my ETL time by running the same package in parallel but I'm having issues finding a good way to save the data to destination.

SETUP:

1. Order table in OLTP.
2. Fact table partitioned by month.
3. Need PostedDate (time when order was paid for) and ShipDate.
4. Order can ship the following month.
5. Since this is a new datawarehouse, I am trying to do each month in parallel to build the historical data.
6. Using SSIS 2014.

GOAL:

1. An ETL process that runs in parallel for each month of data extracted from Order table.

WHAT I HAVE DONE SO FAR:

1. Created a stored procedure that loops through each month.
2. The SP Creates a staging table for that period dynamically with a unique name.

   > StagingTable_'Month'
3. It then creates and executes an SSIS package instance of my ETL process.
4. In the package I am trying to save the data to the correct staging table, but I cannot find a way to do this dynamically.

The idea was to be able to create each month in parallel and then switch each partition in all at once. Instead of doing it in bulks because of memory capacity.

Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried loading the data before trying to optimize it? It sounds rather complex.

Comment: It's easy enough to do if I do not do the ETL in parallel. Then I can just load data using date in bulks. I've got that working. I'm just trying to increase the performance from a few hours (Pulling data from 2003) to hopefully under an hour. Also, I'm curious if this would work because it would be nice to use elsewhere as well.

Comment: What is the bottleneck in the bulk load? Do you think that executing multiple select statements in parallel on your source table will improve the performance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a user variable within a container to store the destination table name then use an expression in your destination to use this variable instead of the table name itself.

Comment: How would I use the variable in my destination task? As far as I understand, OLE DB Destination does not accept parameters and using OLE DB Command will negate the performance increase from parallel work flow by doing RBAR. Do you have an example?

Comment: Two packages. One master with a loop - one child for each month. Pass the month into the package parameter on the child and then create a variable out of that month to represent the table name. In the OLE Destination specify the destination is from a variable and give it the variable you just created. Since a package is fired off asynchronously each month will be loaded in parallel.

Comment: Thanks Rachel! For some reason I was focused on the SQL Command instead of the Table Variable.